# In Review orders page table rate amount has showing wrong,But calculation area amount showing correct and also code override not working- Magento2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am using magento2.3

table rate -> enabled:yes

condition:Weight vs Destination

Ship to Applicable Countries:specific countries

Include Virtual Products in Price Calculation:yes

Calculate Handling Fee:Fixed, Ship to Specific Countries: India
in Review orders page table rate amount showing wrong ,But same page calculation area table rate amount showing correct ,See the below image

[image]

In image Best way(Table Rate) 22.00 has showing it's wrong value,In below Right side Shipping & Handling (Best way - Table Rate) - 15.00 ,Here showing the correct value and calculation also correct.

I try to override with code ,new module has create with app/code/Shipping/ShippingRate/etc/Module.xml file,
app/code/Shipping/ShippingRate/etc/di.xml file,
app/code/Shipping/ShippingRate/registration.php and override files
app/code/Shipping/ShippingRate/Block/Checkout/Overview.php file & app/code/Shipping/ShippingRate/view/frontend/templates/checkout/overview.phtml file, But Code override has not happening ,it doesn't entered into that module..

How to fix this issue??